# City/province/region not included

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

Is there any one who can help me?

I see that Magento by default is US every city and province included.

But for my country, I only can see the name of my country, but i can't see any city drop-down option or  the names of my country city.

Is there any option to include the name of my city/province on the shipping address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can apply directly to Country name with state in database table what you want.

Please refer to this link: http://magentoextension.net/archives/1304

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

by adding this code directly to the Database, my problem is solved.

INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`region_id`, `country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES
    (NULL, 'AO', 'LUANDA', 'Luanda');